# confused about part of the proof if $\lim |a_{n+1}/a_n|=L<1$ then $\lim a_n=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

I am reading several proofs online for part a) of problem below. I am confused how this part is concluded (underlined in yellow color).

---

**Problem 3.** Assume all $s_n \neq 0$ and the limit $L=\lim \left|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}\right|$ exists.

(a) Show that if $L < 1$, then $\lim s_n = 0$.

(b) Show that if $L > 1$, then $\lim |s_n| = +\infty$.

*Solutions.*

(a) Define the sequence $r_n = \left|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n} \right|$ of positive real numbers, and suppose that $\lim r_n = L < 1$. Choose $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $L < a< 1$, and let $\varepsilon = a - L$. Since $r_n \longrightarrow L$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$,
$$ r_n < L+\varepsilon = a.$$
This implies $|s_{n+1}| < a|s_n|$ for all $n \geq N$, and in particular $|s_{N+1}| < a|s_N|$. This is the base case for an induction, where $|s_{N+k}| < a^k |s_N|$ implies

> <sup>*(this is the part underlined in yellow color in OP's image)*</sup>
>
> $|s_{N+k+1}| < a|s_{N+k}| < a^{k+1}|s_N|$, which may be rewritten as the statement $|s_n| < a^{n-N}|s_N|$ for all $n > N$.

We therefore have
$$ 0 \leq |s_n| \leq ca^n \quad \forall n > N, $$

where $c = \frac{|s_N|}{a^N}$ is a constant. Since $a < 1$, the sequence $a^n$ converges to $0$, and $c\cdot a^n \to 0$ also. By the squeeze lemma, it follows that $|s_n| \to 0$ which implies $s_n \to 0$.

---

<sup>Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1dDR.jpg) to see the original image.</sup>

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. Also, avoid the use of images and TYPE your question. If you don't show some effort writing your question, it will be poorly received in this site. Taking the time to write your questions will increase the chances of getting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|s_{N+k+1}| < a|s_{N+k}| < a^2 |s_{N+k-1}| < a^3 |s_{N+k-2}| < \cdots < a^{k+1} |s_N|$$

If you let $n=N+k+1$ and plug this into $|s_{N+k+1}| < a^{k+1} |s_N|$, you have $k=n-N-1$ and $|s_n| < a^{n-N} |s_N|$.